# Find the point that minimizes the summation of L_\infty norms to three given points

Tags: convex-optimization, norms

Given three points $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$, $\omega_3 \in \mathbb{R}^d$, how can I find the point $\omega \in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that the summation of its $\ell_\infty$ distances to these three points are minimized, i.e., 
$$\min_\omega \{ \Vert \omega-\omega_1\Vert_\infty + \Vert\omega-\omega_2\Vert_\infty + \Vert\omega-\omega_3\Vert_\infty\}.$$
I am wondering will the optimal $\omega$ be one of the three points $\{\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3\}$ or under what kind of condition will the optimal $\omega$ be obtained at one of the three points?

Furthermore, can the results be generalized to more than 3 points?

Comment: I don't know the answer but wanted to remark that this is a special case of generalized medians.